# Como tirar a semana epidemiológica 00 do gráfico?

Tags: r, data, ggplot2

tenho um gráfico de setas em que a base de dados está por semana epidemiológica. Na base está tudo certo, sem a semana 00, só que quando eu ploto, a semana aparece.

script que utilizei pra gerar a semana epidemiológica, a partir da coluna de data que tinha no dataframe original:
[tabela gerada com os script abaixo - tab2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H24QT.png)

```
date=data.frame(date_week=seq.Date(from=as.Date("2023-01-01"), 

to=max(tab1$data),by="days")) 

date$week=paste0(epiweek(date$date_week),".",epiyear(date$date_week)) 

date$semana=weekdays(date$date_week)

date=date[which(date$semana=="Saturday"),]  

tab1$week=paste0(epiweek(tab1$data),".",epiyear(tab1$data))

tab2=merge(tab1,date,by="week",all.x=T)
```

*script para o gráfico*

```
ggplot_waterfall(tab2,'date_week','total', nArrowSize = 0.4)+
  theme_classic() +
  theme(strip.text = element_text(hjust = 0.5,size=8 ),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 8L, face = "bold"),
        axis.text.x  = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 10, angle = 0, hjust = .5, vjust = .5, face = "plain"),
        axis.text.y  = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 10, angle = 0, hjust = 1, vjust = 0, face = "plain"),  
        axis.title.x = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 10, angle = 0, hjust = .5, vjust = 0, face = "plain"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 10, angle = 90, hjust = .3, vjust = .5, face = "plain"),
        legend.text=element_text(size=10),
        text=element_text(size=10),
        title = element_text(size=10),legend.position = "bottom")+
  scale_x_date(date_breaks="7 week",labels = label_date_short(format = c("%Y", "%U")),expand = c(0,10))
```

[gráfico com a semana epidemiológica 00](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ode5z.png)

Então como que eu faço para  essa semana não aparecer? Eu não sei se é o scale_x_date ou se é o plot que não aceita semana epidemiológica...

Comment: Imagens não são uma boa maneira de por dados, veja este [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Pode, por favor, [editar a pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/593110/edit) com a saída de `dput(tab2)` ou, se a base for muito grande, de `dput(head(tab2, 20))`?

Comment: `epiweek`, etc e `ggplot_waterfall` não são funções R base. Ao usar funções que não são funções R base, inicie os scripts com chamadas a `library(pkgname)` para carregar os pacotes necessários.

Comment: Muito obrigada pelas considerações Rui Barras! Eu consegui encontrar o problema... Era no scale_x_date! Tem que colocar um "%V" no lugar com do "%U"